# Where can I find listings of "taken" identifiers in standard libraries

Tags: c++, list, identifier

With the large size of current C/C++ libraries like STL, Win32, Boost, posix etc. the question of what identifiers are problematic arises. Even with namespaces it is nice to be able to select identifiers which don't clash with the most used identifiers of other libraries when desiging a new library designed to work togheter with existing ones.

At least for the C++ standard libraries (including 0x) there should be listings available. It would be reasonable to think that someone has done a tool for this purpose, which reads a set of header files and creates a list of all names ordered by namespace. Anyone who knows of such a tool? The tool should preferably read all headers in a directory tree rather than only those #included by a particular cpp file.

Comment: Is doxygen the tool you're after?

Answer (score 4):

> Even with namespaces it is nice to be able to select identifiers which don't clash with the most used identifiers of other libraries when desiging a new library designed to work togheter with existing ones.

I realize that quite a few libraries do that but this attempt is fundamentally misguided.

Don’t design your identifiers so that they don’t clash, design them so that they are clear, short, and descriptive. These should be the only criteria.

Identifier clash is a solved problem, thanks to namespaces. Properly used, name clash simply doesn’t arise.

Comment: "Properly used, name clash simply doesn’t arise." - except sometimes with ADL. For example, it is highly unrecommended to define a free function `swap` with semantics differing from those of `std::swap`. In practice that's the only function I know of that is widely expected to be overloaded via ADL, but in principle any time a library introduces one, it pollutes every namespace. If some caller does `using std::sort` in order to call `sort` without full qualification, then they potentially introduce a clash with any namespace containing its own `sort` function.

Comment: @Steve: true but that’s not such a big problem because it can be fixed by explicit qualification as soon as a clash occurs. This is only a local change (unless `using` is used globally in a header, in which case all hell breaks loose).

Comment: @Konrad: fair point. Without namespaces, the equivalent clash in C is a nightmare.

Comment: I know, of course, that apart from macros names don't clash in C++ with proper namespace usage. Nevertheless keeping clear of having to qualify a large percentage of identifiers is a courtesy to library users. Apart from that I was planning to use macros and that was what made the need more important. Now, as always, many of you will protest: NONONO don't use macros. But in this case there is no real alternative. Writing the code in longhand will be so tedious that the library would be totally useless. With the macros it is really really neat.

Comment: @Bengt: using macros is fine. But these macros **must** (!!!) begin with a library-specific identifier, e.g. `MYLIBRARY_SOME_MACRO`. That way (and **only** that way) there is no danger of name clashes. Otherwise your library must be considered broken.

Comment: Well, I know all of that of course. And that's exactly why I want to scan for identifiers. The reason to this, in turn, is that there will be a very high macro density in the parts of the code using the library, and prefixing them all would render the source code much less readable. Also, as I have done my utmost to avoid as many macros as possible it will be rather hard for the user to know which entities are macros, thus the prefixing increases the learning threshold, and ease of use is the primary purpose!

Answer (score -1):

How about using egrep? [Mumble mumble to get 30 characters]

Comment: 1. Because writing a regex to do this would not be trivial. You would need a more powerful tool to do this. 2. Because the locations of all files which might be `#included` probably are not known in advance.

Comment: Yes, the regex would not be easy (possible?) to design. No, I don't want the #include tree define what to scan, I'm interested in what is in a library, thus all files in a directory(tree).